# Pester how to test powershell script which does not have functions?

Tags: powershell, pester

I have Azure powershell function which run.ps1 looks pretty much

```
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Write-Host $Request.Param1
Write-Host $Request.ParamB
Write-Host $Request.ParamC
return 200
```

This is in the directory /func/myFunction/run.ps1
And my pester test is in the /func/Tests/my.Tests.ps1

And the test looks like

```
using namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis

Describe "Test Run" {
    BeforeAll {
        $FunctionDir = $PSScriptRoot.Replace('Tests', 'myFunction')
        . $FunctionDir\run.ps1
    }

    It "Can get OK" {
        $Request = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ParamA = 'A'
            ParamB = 'B'
            ParamC = 'C'
        }
        $result = run -Request $Request
        $result | Should -Be 200
    }
}
```

When invoking my test I get "the term run' is not recognized...

How could I run the complete script with Pester and test the output of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way around this is to use [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias):

```
BeforeAll {
    $FunctionDir = $PSScriptRoot.Replace('Tests', 'myFunction')
    Set-Alias -Name Run -Value $FunctionDir\run.ps1
}
```